# Getting "produced no reply for request Message"

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration framework in my project. The database is db2 running on AS400. I have to call two stored procedures one after another. My first stored procedure is executed without any issues and passing the message to the second stored-proc-outbound-gateway. Here, weird thing is happening. It appears that the second stored procedure is executed successfully, but strangely the the second stored-proc-outbound-gateway is not producing any reply message.

The following are the log statements after I connect to SQL server:

```
[org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInCallableStatement] CallableStatement.execute() returned 'true'      
[org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInCallableStatement] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1   
[org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned 1   
[org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
```

The same statements are different when I connect to db2:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInCallableStatement] CallableStatement.execute() returned 'false'   
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.doInCallableStatement] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned 0  
DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.extractReturnedResults] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
```

Can any one please say what's wrong here?
Please feel free to ask me if you need any additional info.

Here is the complete spring-integration file for your reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd  ">

    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-InputChannel" />

    <int:chain  input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-InputChannel"  output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SetDateTag" >

        <!-- Transformer to transform the resultXml to the user understandable form using XSLT -->
        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQPutUserBAInformationSetDateTag}"  /> 

    </int:chain>

        <int:chain input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SetDateTag" output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall" >

        <!-- Split the Search Request Params from Xml  -->
        <int-xml:xpath-splitter>
            <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="//AWDPQContactID"  namespace-map="xmlMessageNamespace" />
        </int-xml:xpath-splitter>   
        <!-- Store the original payload in header for future purpose -->
        <int:header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
            <int:header name="${headerNames.originalPayload}" expression="payload" />   
        </int:header-enricher>  
    </int:chain>    

    <!-- PQPutUserBAInformation Channel -->
    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall" />
    <int:chain input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall" output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage1-Response"   >

        <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="buildRequestBasedDataSource" />

        <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
                        id="PQPutUserBAInformation-AWD-StoredProcedure" 
                        auto-startup="true"
                        data-source="routingDataSource" 
                        stored-procedure-name="ZSPPQDELETEUSERIDBA"
                        skip-undeclared-results="true"
                        ignore-column-meta-data="true"  
                        use-payload-as-parameter-source = "false" 
                        expect-single-result="true" >

                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_USERID" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_BUSINESSAREA" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />


                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_USERID" expression="#xpath(payload, '//CurrentUserID')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_BUSINESSAREA" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Code')" />


                <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="rowMapper" row-mapper="com.dsths.cs.awd.utils.ResultSetRowMapper"/>

        </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
    </int:chain>

    <!-- Service Activator to build the Message from the Stored Procedure ResultSet -->
    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage1-Response" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage1-Response"
                           output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2-Translate"
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" /> 

    <!-- Service Activator to build the Message from the Stored Procedure ResultSet -->
    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2-Translate" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2-Translate"
                           output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2"
                           ref="cacheRequestHandler" 
                           method="translatePassword" />                           

    <!-- PQPutUserBAInformation Channel -->
    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2" />
    <int:chain input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCall2" output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage2-Response"   >

        <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="buildRequestBasedDataSource" />

        <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
                        id="PQPutUserBAInformation-AWD-StoredProcedure2" 
                        auto-startup="true"
                        data-source="routingDataSource" 
                        stored-procedure-name="ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA"
                        skip-undeclared-results="true"
                        ignore-column-meta-data="true"  
                        use-payload-as-parameter-source = "false" 
                        expect-single-result="true" >

                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_USERID" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_BUSINESSAREA" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_SELECTEDIND" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_DEFAULTIND" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LEGACYSYSTEM" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LEGACYLOGIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LEGACYPASSWORD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_OTHERLOGIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_OTHERPASSWORD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ADDSECURLOGIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ADDSECURPASSWORD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LASTUPDATEUSERID" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LASTUPDATE" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />


                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_USERID" expression="#xpath(payload, '//CurrentUserID')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_BUSINESSAREA" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Code')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_SELECTEDIND" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Selected')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_DEFAULTIND" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Default')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LEGACYSYSTEM" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/LegacySystem')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LEGACYLOGIN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/LegacyLogin')" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LEGACYPASSWORD" expression="headers.LegacyPassword" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_OTHERLOGIN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/OtherLogin')" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_OTHERPASSWORD" expression="headers.otherPassword" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ADDSECURLOGIN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/AddSecurLogin')" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ADDSECURPASSWORD" expression="headers.addSecurPassword" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LASTUPDATEUSERID" expression="#xpath(payload, '//userID')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LASTUPDATE" expression="#xpath(payload, '//dateTimeStamp')" />

                <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="rowMapper" row-mapper="com.dsths.cs.awd.utils.ResultSetRowMapper"/>

        </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
    </int:chain>

        <!-- Service Activator to build the Message from the Stored Procedure ResultSet -->
    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage2-Response" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage2-Response"
                           output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-Enrich-SPCallStage2"                      
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="buildMessageFromExtSysResponse" />                       

    <!--  Service Activator to build the jobResponse xml making use of jobRequestXml and xlst transformed xml-->
    <int:channel id="PQPutUserBAInformation-Enrich-SPCallStage2" />
    <int:service-activator input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-Enrich-SPCallStage2" 
                           output-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-CleanUp" 
                           ref="msgHandler" 
                           method="enrichPayloadXml" />

    <int:chain  input-channel="PQPutUserBAInformation-CleanUp" >

        <!-- Transformer to transform the resultXml to the user understandable form using XSLT -->
        <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQPutUserBAInformationCleanUp}"  /> 

    </int:chain>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the stored proc produced no result.

Comment: Thanks for the response.The same stored procedure was working fine earlier with SQL server database, but it is not working with AS400 database now. Any guess?

Comment: The control/Message is not reaching the next output channel **PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage2-Respons** after hitting the second stored procedure..Looks like something is wrong after connecting to AS400 database.

Comment: Still unable to figure out what the problem is..It would be great if you can help me by looking at the log file...Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about AS400; all I can say is that message means the SP returned no result. If there was an exception connecting, it would have been thrown.

Comment: Actually I am trying to connect to db2 database that is existing on AS400. **ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA** is a stored procedure that inserts a record.Strangely, the record is inserted successfully and the response is not reaching the output channel **PQPutUserBAInformation-SPCallStage2-Respons**. The same thing was working fine with SQL server database. Any ideas on what could be wrong here.... Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question with more simple log statements.I think it would be now easy for you to say why no message is being sent to the next channel.It would be great if you can help me please

Comment: That just confirms what I have been saying all along, the DB2 stored procedure returned no results.

Comment: Thanks for the response..Ok..Does it mean that the stored procedure returned result When I connect to SQL Server and no result when I connect to DB2?If no result is produced by a stored procedure, then no message will be sent to the output channel...as a result, the application will be hanged waiting for the message.....is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes; but it's not hung; the flow simply terminates at that time. The resolution depends on your application requirements. If you never expect a reply, use an outbound-channel-adapter instead of a gateway. If you always expect a reply, set `requires-reply="true"` and an exception is thrown if no reply is received. There's no standard way to handle a case where you sometimes get a reply and sometimes don't. For that, you would need to invoke the stored procedure yourself (with a `JdbcTemplate`) and invoke your code with a `<service-activator/>`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and I fixed it, the exception means the transform step returns null(shouldn't be null) because the message I created cant be properly transformed. Try to debug into the transform step, and see what is the outcome.  the exception happened in my second line:

```js
IntegrationFlows.from(testChannel() )
           .transform( new ObjectTransformer() )
           .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass,
```